# Python PEX: Pack a package with its sub-packages

Tags: python, pex

I have such a structure

```
$ tree -h
.
├── [1.0K]  myproj
│   ├── [   0]  index.py
│   ├── [   0]  __init__.py
│   └── [1.0K]  models
│       ├── [   0]  __init__.py
│       ├── [   0]  mymodels.py
│       └── [   0]  othermodels.py
├── [296K]  myproj.pex
└── [ 106]  setup.py

$ cat setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='myproj',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

I want to pack entire `myproj` package (including `myproj.models` sub-package) into a pex file.
I run `pex . -o myproj.pex` but `myproj.models` is absent from the pex archive:

```
...
├── [1.0K]  .deps
│   └── [1.0K]  myproj-0.0.0-py2-none-any.whl
│       ├── [1.0K]  myproj
│       │   ├── [   0]  index.py
│       │   └── [   0]  __init__.py
│       └── [1.0K]  myproj-0.0.0.dist-info
...
```

How can I pack the whole package?

Answer (score 1):

A quick n dirty way is to put a `MANIFEST.in` file in `myproj` directory that says:

```
global-include *.py
```