# Is there a way to include extra files when building a PEX (i.e. with MANIFEST.in)?

Tags: python, python-pex

I have a directory structure similar to the following:

```
├── myproj
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── auth.py
│   │   └── stuff.py
├── html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── about.html
├── MANIFEST.in
├── setup.cfg 
└── setup.py
```

The contents of MANIFEST.in are:

```
graft html
```

The following post alludes to being able to use `MANIFEST.in` with PEX ([Python PEX: Pack a package with its sub-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456962/python-pex-pack-a-package-with-its-sub-packages)) but when I run either `pex . -o myproject` or `python setup.py bdist_pex` the `html/` directory is not included, verified via `unzip -Z1 myproject` on the resulting output, but it is included when running `python setup.py sdist`.

How do I include these extra html files when building a PEX binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a `MANIFEST.in` alone isn't enough. You also need to set the `include_package_data` option to `True` in `setup.cfg`.

This option will include extra files found in the package so you must also move the `html` directory inside the `myproj` package.

So the directory structure looks like:

```
├── myproj
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── auth.py
│   │   └── stuff.py
│   ├── html
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── about.html
├── MANIFEST.in
├── setup.cfg 
└── setup.py
```

The contents of MANIFEST.in are:

```
graft myproj/html
```

And setup.cfg contains in the `[options]` section:

```
include_package_data = True
```